# javascript array cycling only first var

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, iframe, var

I am using javascript to cycle through an array of urls within an iframe and so far when the prev or next buttons are pressed it jumps to the first var in the array and both prev and next functions end. Any ideas?

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://startpage.com" width="484px" height = "424px"></iframe>
<button onclick = "prevPage(); ">Prev</button>
<button onclick = "nextPage(); ">Next</button>

<script>

var sites=new Array(); 
sites[0]="http://site1.html";       
sites[1]="http://site2.html";
sites[2]="http://site3.html";
sites[3]="http://site4.html";

function nextPage() {
var number = document.getElementById("myFrame").src;
number = number.substring(number.length - 4 ,number.length-3);
number = parseInt(number) + 1; 
document.getElementById("myFrame").src=sites[0];
} 

function prevPage() {
var number = document.getElementById("myFrame").src;
number = number.substring(number.length - 3 ,number.length-4);
number = parseInt(number) - 1; 
document.getElementById("myFrame").src=sites[0];
} 

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using the URL as your 'position' storage? It'd be FAR easier to just use a variable:

```
var curPos = 0;

function nextPage() {
   curPos++;
   if (curPos >= sites.length) {
      curPos = 0;
   }
   document.getElementById('myframe').src = sites[curPos];
}

function prevPage() {
    curPos--;
    if (curPos < 0) {
       curPos = sites.length - 1;
    }
    document.getElementById('myframe'.).src = sites[curPos];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly I think all you need to do is use `document.getElementById("myFrame").src=sites[number];` instead of `document.getElementById("myFrame").src=sites[0];`

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a shot but the buttons ceased to function and firebug didn't spit out any console errors... hmm...I'll keep banging away, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").src=sites[number-1];
```

is what you are trying to do in both functions.

Comment: This returned a local file search instead of the array urls